# How can I convert eps to jpg?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

how can i convert eps image to jpg/png. any good application you can suggest.

Comment: More options, and discussion, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107845/converting-eps-to-png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download application called GIMP - http://www.gimp.org/downloads/

and then install eps ghostscript - http://www.community.contractwebdevelopment.com/install-ghostscript-windows-and-gimp

The above link also contains few instructions which you may need to follow

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! i have gimp already and the ghostcript worked perfect!

Answer (score 8):

Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php): `convert something.eps something.png`